# Pass variables dynamically to multiple instances of a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a list of clickable elements dynamically that should all have a onclick event which should call a function. My issue is I also want to pass parameters to this function dynamically i.e. the onclick function should have different parameters. I am struggling to get the parameters to be dynamically passed here is my code:

Note: listToRender is an array of JSON objects.

```
var wrapper = jQuery('#helper-results-parent');
var article_tmp = jQuery('#news-article-child');
var news_article = article_tmp;
for (var i = 0, j = listToRender.length; i < j; i++) {
    var title = listToRender[i].title;
    news_article.find('.title').html(title);
    news_article.find('.publishdate').html(listToRender[i].created);
    news_article.find('.link').click(function 
    ({getNewsArticles.apply(this, ['article',i]);});
    wrapper.append(news_article);
    news_article = article_tmp.clone(1);
}
```

My issue is I am struggling to pass the value of "i" to the getNewsArticles function dynamically so that each list item has a different value of i for its clickable event. Instead of passing the integer value of i, the literal string letter i is passed to the function.

Comment: What's the nature of the struggle you're having? What's supposed to happen? What happens instead? What's the function you're calling look like?

Comment: Instead of passing the integer value of i, the literal string letter i is passed to the function.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. You should not use `var i` but `let i` in the loop: `for (let i = 0, j = listToRender.length` or better yet; use forEach: `listToRender.forEach(({title,created},i)=>{...`

Comment: Not clear from your question, but you may be misunderstanding how to use [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).